# Question mark or period for the mentioned sentence?

Tags: punctuation

> Is such an act necessary, one might ask

Does the above sentence need a question mark or a period?

Answer (score 1):

A question mark wouldn't apply to the whole sentence, because the main part of the sentence is "one might ask".

You could put a question mark after the actual question if you separate the question out into a quote or something like that, like:

> "Is such an act necessary?", one might ask.

Comment: I think it could be punctuated even less awkwardly with a rearrangement: _One might ask: Is such an act necessary?_ (Though this doesn't really answer the question, I thought it might be worth a mention in the comments.)